# Does it matter if I installed Trusty packages such as libunwind8 when my version of Ubuntu is Xenial?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, package-management, dependencies

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday due to a month of troubleshooting fails with Windows 7 on this 9 year old ASUS notebook.

I decided to completely remove Windows and start fresh with Linux. Sure enough it runs without problems. I use this laptop for development using technologies such as VS Code, .NET Core, C, C++, JS, Node.js, MongoDB, etc.

When installing .NET core I realized I had to install the Ubuntu prerequisites one by one. Whenever I would download the next package I'd see (Trust) or (Xenial) and to be honest I had no idea what meant what.

I realize now that was a rookie mistake since it showed the version of Ubuntu next to the download as well and perhaps because of my migraine I decided to ignore it. Now those packages are installed but are all Trusty. .NET Core installed and runs fine. Will this be an issue?

Or will I need to install all packages again this time for Xenial?

Comment: Yes & No.   The problem is software changes and the API/ABI between Trusty (14.04) & Xenial (16.04) may have changed in portions, so you may have a ticking time bomb installed that will only blow if you make a specific call using the wrong interface (ie. a xenial call with xx-bytes when the lib/dependency expects xy-bytes [or xx-bytes formatted differently]).  Most things will be the same, but I don't code in most of your langs and have no idea. It's a risk, and being a coder you'll have to explore what you installed & look at changes were made (14.04->16.04) to access risk.. my 2c

Comment: A quick scan of your example - libunwind8 looks pretty safe; but I don't use the package so my limit of scan was comparing https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libunwind8 with the xenial version (and I didn't explore http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/libu/libunwind/libunwind_1.1-4.1/changelog)

Comment: Another thought (maybe I was too pessimistic) :  .deb Packages have rules in them that attempt to stop breakage, so assuming the devs who made & packaged them did everything correctly & limited install the matching ... your apt*/dpkg install should be okay (esp. older packages into newer system; as devs should have thought about the history & coded to avoid breakage).